# Xamarin Forms 5 compiling to android not working

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

After updating my project to Xamarin Forms 5.0 I cant run it on my phone. I tried a blank Xamarin Forms 5.0 project and it worked, but my real project prints "Deployment was successful to [Device]" but nothing happends. It installs the app but it is corrupted or something, because the app is not visible on home screen, but exists in "settings > app" with no icon (and the size 154mb as it should be)

I have no idea what causes this and have tried everything to make it run on my phone. When archiving it I get "Cannot create archive file because the copy of mdbs files failed"

I get no compile errors when I press Build -> Build solution

1. I have tried deleting the app via adb/system and reinstalling it via vs.
2. I have tried removing the obj and bin folders and rebuilding.
3. I have tried rebooting and reinstalling android sdk.
4. I have tried restarting the android abs server

My phone is android-28 and the minsdk is 21, targetsdk is 29

(Xamarin.Forms v5.0.0.1874, Xamarin.Essentials v1.6.0, Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.4)

full build log when trying to debug: https://pastebin.com/dgqQvh24

```
1>Deployment was successful to [DEVICE].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by an invalid AndroidManifest.xml file. Simply removing a duplicate  tag caused the build to succeed. For some reason xamarin forms 4.8 ignored this in the building process, but xamarin forms 5 "Failed to parse Activity Name" because of the duplicate  tag.

For anyone expericing this issue just fix the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: This answer addresses a compile error, yet the question states it compiles fine, but doesn't deploy properly. I am experiencing what is described in the question: no compile error, a "Deployment was successful" message, but an app that appears in the OS' app list, yet has no icon on the home screen/app tray.

The last time I tried this upgrade to 5, I experienced this deployment issue, and THEN suddenly began having the compile error mentioned in this answer. (!)

Comment: It is a runtime error with setting the main activity, so I dont know what to call it. It compile fine, however android itself says that it is wrongly compiled because of the duplicate mainacitivy header. So I think it is a sort of compiler error however a more accureate statement is calling it a faulty deployment error.

Comment: @TimotheeHowland as stated in the question + answer, The problem is how xamarin makes the AndroidManifest.xml automaticly and some code handeling the AndroidManifest was changed so it now included invalid .xml that was previously removed. The compiled succesfully only was to explain that NONE of my C# code was the reason for the error.